# How can i replace a parameter by looping parameters in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, parameters

I have an array of parameters and i want to replace all parameters by looping over array in ruby on rails.

I am using before_action in controller as

```
before_action :cost_format
```

This is an array of parameters. The format of the parameter is string, i want to run a function on each parameter and convert it into float. So i am looping an array and calling function on each element.

```
 def cost_format
    x = [params[:cost_1], params[:cost_2], params[:cost_3]]
    x.each do |i|
      convert_cost(i)
    end
 end
```

I have a function convert_cost as following

```
 def convert_cost(x)
   x.gsub(',', '.').to_f
 end
```

How do i loop an array so that my parameters get replaced.? Parameters are not being replaced by above code. Any hint would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Try `map` instead of `each`.

Comment: map also doesn't works. For instance 

    [1] pry(main)> x = 1
    => 1
    [2] pry(main)> y = 2 
    => 2
   [3] pry(main)> z = 3
   => 3
   [4] pry(main)> a = [x, y, z]
   => [1, 2, 3]
   [5] pry(main)> a
   => [1, 2, 3]
   [6] pry(main)> a.map{|i| i.to_s}
   => ["1", "2", "3"]
   [7] pry(main)> x
   => 1

this is run in console

Comment: Is the intent to mutate the original `params`, or have a mutated copy?

Comment: I think, as @3limin4t0r is suggesting, your question is underspecified. `map`, according to your example in comments, is indeed converting integers to strings and returning that array of strings. It is *not* converting the value of `x` (not mutating `x`). I think a more complete example would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll want something like this:

```
def cost_format
  %i(cost_1 cost_2 cost_3).each do |key|
    params[key] = convert_cost(params[key])
  end
end

def convert_cost(val)
  val.gsub(',', '.').to_f
end
```

This grabs each key from your `params` and replaces the value with it passed through the `convert_cost` method.

---

*Edit: you might be able to ignore this section about `convert_cost` due if it works with the format you're getting your numbers in. Please excuse my ethnocentrism :)*

I've not updated your `convert_cost` method, though I'm a little wary about whether it will work at the moment. If you've got, for example `"1,234,567"` and you call your `gsub` you get `"1.234.567"`. Calling `to_f` on that gives you `1.234`, which I wouldn't think you'd want?

Instead of that, you could use:

```
def convert_cost(val)
  val.gsub(',', '').to_f
end
```

E.G.

```
convert_cost("1,234,567")
# => 1234567.0
```

---

Combining all that, the following would be converted like so:

```
params = { cost_1: "1,234,567", cost_2: "123", cost_3: "456.5", cost_4: "I won't be touched" }
# after `cost_format` before_action runs:
# => {:cost_1=>1234567.0, :cost_2=>123.0, :cost_3=>456.5, :cost_4=>"I won't be touched"}
```

Let me know how you get on or if you have any question - hope this helps.

Comment: `%i(cost_1 cost_2 cost_3)` could also be replaced with `(:cost_1..:cost_3)` if you prefer the range syntax.

Comment: Thanks @3limin4t0r, good tip - I hadn't even thought to use a range with symbols :) As always, an interesting addition and something new!

Comment: FYI, reason to convert `,` into `.` is because some countries (including mine) use the `,` to denote decimals, we use the `.` for as thousand separator. For example `1.234,25`

Comment: Ah, that would explain it - might need some internationalisation thrown into the mixer too. Does `to_f` take into account a locale when using Rails or will a change like I've popped into place still be necessary? (Edit: seems it's pulled directly from Ruby.)

Comment: I don't have much experience with that, I mostly use `<input type="number" />` to avoid this issue since the web-browser will submit the data in international format.

Comment: "Does to_f take into account a locale when using Rails or will a change like I've popped into place still be necessary?", no it does not. `"1,234,567".to_f == 1.0`.

Comment: Thanks @max - that was the conclusion I came to, though definitely one worth knowing.

Comment: You can see the same behavior if you do `"1234garbage".to_f == 123.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try something like

```
x.map{|param| param.gsub(',', '.').to_f}
```

directly on your array.

So your `cost_format` method will look like:

```
def cost_format
  x = [params[:cost_1], params[:cost_2], params[:cost_3]]
  result = x.map{|param| param.gsub(',', '.').to_f}
  # do stuff with result
end
```

I think the reason it's not working because, each method returns its receiver, but `map` returns a new array.

Comment: Although you explain that `map` returns a new array. It might be a good idea to assign it to something like `result` to make clear that from that point on the variable `result` contains the correctly formatted array. This is not always necessary, but from the way the question is formulated OP seems somewhat new to Ruby in general.